# Converting a string rappresentation of a file (byte array) back to a file in C#

Tags: c#, file-upload, encoding, file-encodings

As in the title I'm trying to convert back a string rappresentation of a bytearray to the original file where the bytes where taken.

**What I've done:**

I've a web service that gets a whole file and sends it:

```
answer.FileByte = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\QRY.txt");
```

After the serialization in the transmitted result xml I've this line:

```
<a:FileByte>TVNIfGF8MjAxMzAxMDF8YQ1QSUR8YXxhfGF8YXxhfGF8YXwyMDEzMDEwMXxhfGF8YXxhfGF8YXxhfGF8YXxhfGF8YXxhDVBWMXxhfGF8YXxhfGF8YXxhfGF8YXxhfDIwMTMwMTAxfDIwMTMwMTAxfDB8MHxhDQo=</a:FileByte>
```

I've tried to convert it back with this line in another simple application:

```
//filepath is the path of the file created
//bytearray is the string from the xml (copypasted)
File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bytearray));
```

I've used UTF8 as enconding since the xml declares to use this charset. Keeping the datatype is not an option since I'm writing a simple utility to check the file conversion.

Maybe I'm missing something very basic but I'm not able to come up with a working solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This certainly isn't UTF8, the serializer probably converted it to Base64.

Use `Convert.FromBase64String()` to get your bytes back

Assuming that bytearray is the `"TVNIfGF8M..."` string, try:

```
string bytearray = ...;
File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, Convert.FromBase64String(bytearray));
```

Answer (score 1):

UTF8 is a way to convert arbitrary *text* into bytes.
It was used by `ReadAllText()` to turn the bytes on disk back into XML.

You're seeing a mechanism to convert arbitrary *bytes* into text that can fit into XML.  (that text is then convert to different bytes using UTF8).

It's probably Base64; use `Convert.FromBase64String()`.